# Replace html string/tag to another html string/tag android

Tags: android

I want to replace html tag to another tag like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= htmlarray.size(); i++) 
{
    Content = Content.replaceAll("<Sup><FONT size=\"+1\">" + i+ "<","<Sup><FONT size=\"+2\"><a style=\"color: #664b38\"href=\"http:/"+ i + "\">" + i + "</a><");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer and here it is:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(target).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

This function worked for me. And also using `replace()` function.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= htmlarray.size(); i++) 
{
 Content = Content.replace("<Sup><FONT size=\"+1\">" + i+ "<","<Sup><FONT size=\"+2\"><a style=\"color: #664b38\"href=\"http:/"+ i + "\">" + i + "</a><");
}
```